# Copying rows to a wksheet based on the value in a specific column isn't applying to my whole spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping over values in Column B of the current worksheet. If the value's length is 8 characters, copy the WHOLE row to another sheet. 
It is kind of working, but I'm missing around a hundred rows that should have been copied.

I guess it's to do with the format of the cell values in Column B. There are some that are just Text headers which will definitely not meet the criteria. The ones that it should copy are all in this format (Column B):

```
6008571X
60088242
....
```

The rows I'm interested in have 8 characters in Column B. The problem is that some of them might be formatted as numbers some as text (or perhaps preceded by ').

```
Sub aims()
    Dim i As Long
    'Get the address of the first non blank cell in Row B from the bottom
    MyFirstBlankAddress = Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Address
    'Extract the number from the address to get the row number
    MyRowNumber = Split(MyFirstBlankAddress, "$")(2)

    For i = 1 To MyRowNumber
        With Range("B" & i)
            If Len(.Value) = 8 Then .EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I was expecting 410 rows copied, while only 276 got copied.

EDIT: I have been reading your answers/suggestions and testing stuff. I've found out that the problem lies elsewhere. My original code identifies the rows in a correct way, it's something to do with copying.

If I change my code to just highlight the matching rows, it matches all the right rows:

```
If Len(.Value) = 8 Then .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
```

Comment: First, check that `MyRowNumber` returns the number you're expecting. If it does, there might be hidden characters, trailing spaces etc.

Comment: You could add a LEN formula to your sheet to check.

Comment: MyRowNumber returns the right number. That's what I'm thinking. There must be something hidden.

Comment: And add a Trim to your code.

Comment: Thanks.have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do the copy/paste, which is where your issue is, but the below works.

```
Sub aims()
Dim i As Long
Dim vLastRow As Long
Dim s2 As Long

'find last row in sheet, or you could change to find last row in specified column
'Example: Cells = Columns(column number or letter), Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, column number)
vLastRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
s2 = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To vLastRow
    If Trim(Len(CStr(Cells(i, 2)))) = 8 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range(Cells(s2, 1).Address)
        s2 = s2 + 1
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It did not copy anything. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks.You've just edited something and it works fine. What have you changed?

Comment: I changed Sheets("Sheet2") to Sheets(2) because I was guessing your sheet name might be different, hence the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you for marking it as the answer. I would suggest using urdearboy's answer as it is almost instantaneous, and much faster than mine.

Comment: s2 is not defined in his answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. The below code attempts to copy everything at once instead of having many instances of copy/paste. The two tests are seeing if the trimmed value has a character length of 8 OR if the trimmed value has a character length of 9 but the last character is the apostrophe. If either of these criteria are met, we will add that cell to a `Union`.

Once the code has looped through all rows, it will copy the entire union at all once

```
Option Explicit

Sub shooter()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, Add As Boolean, CopyMe As Range
Dim x As Range

LR = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each x In ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)
  Add = False

    If Len(Trim(x)) = 8 Then
        Add = True
    ElseIf Len(Trim(x)) = 9 And Right(Trim(x), 1) = "'" Then
        Add = True
    End If

    If Add Then
        If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyMe = Union(CopyMe, x)
        Else
            Set CopyMe = x
        End If
    End If

Next x

If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
    CopyMe.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range(“A1”)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When you posted 'Paste here, what exactly do I need to paste? I pasted: CopyMe.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) but it didn't copy anything to sheet3